# SQL: Ignore Condition in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am confused on how to exclude one of the conditions in WHERE clause if it evaluates to NULL

```
SELECT TB1.COL3 
FROM TB1, TB2
WHERE TB1.COL1 = TB2.Col1
AND TB2.COL1 = '12345'
AND (TB2.COL3 = (SELECT MIN(TB3.COL4)
FROM TB3
WHERE COL1 = TB2.COL1
AND COL2 in ('A', 'B') 
AND COL4 IN (SELECT COL3 FROM TB4 
WHERE COL1 = TB4.COL1))) 
AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

How can I modify the above query to ignore the "AND condition TB2.COL3" if the following condition SELECT MIN(TB3.COL4) FROM TB3 evaluates to some value except NULL. If NULL the above query should be executed as below:

```
SELECT TB1.COL3 
FROM TB1, TB2
WHERE TB1.COL1 = TB2.Col1
AND TB2.COL1 = '12345'
AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: The query is very confusing. In `SELECT COL3 FROM TB2 WHERE COL1 = TB2.COL1` you are missing a qualifier. It gets evaluated as `SELECT COL3 FROM TB2 WHERE TB2.COL1 = TB2.COL1`, because TB2 is the table you are working with in the subquery. And as TB2.COL1 = TB2.COL1` is always true except for null, you end up with `SELECT COL3 FROM TB2 WHERE TB2.COL1 IS NOT NULL`. Is this intended?

Comment: On a side note: Comma-separated joins where made redundant in SQL in 1992. Please use explicit joins (`FROM TB1 INNER JOIN TB2 ON ...`). Then, a query is hard to read when it's all uppercase. Either just leave the keywords in uppercase or just put it all in lowercase. Then, your query is not very readable because of the lack of indention. Where does the first subquery start and end, where the second? At last: Must you join TB2? You are not selecting from it, so I'd rather expect `IN` or `EXISTS`. With a join you may run the risk of getting duplicate result rows.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have modified the SQL replacing TB2 with TB4 to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could pull this off with a coalesce:

```
SELECT TB1.COL3 
FROM TB1, TB2
WHERE TB1.COL1 = TB2.Col1
AND TB2.COL1 = '12345'
AND (TB2.COL3 = COALESCE((SELECT MIN(TB3.COL4)
FROM TB3
WHERE COL1 = TB2.COL1
AND COL2 in ('A', 'B') 
AND COL4 IN (SELECT COL3 FROM TB2 
WHERE COL1 = TB2.COL1)), TB2.COL3)) 
AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Here we are just wrapping that SELECT statement in `COALESCE` which, if it returns null, will grab the second parameter's value instead, which is the same column we are comparing. Since `TB2.COL3 = TB2.COL3` is obviously `TRUE` then this filter will not have any impact on the result set.

Also, it's generally recommended that you stop using comma's in your FROM clause and use proper JOIN syntax. It's been around for over 2 decades now:

```
SELECT
    TB1.COL3
FROM
    TB1
    INNER JOIN TB2
        ON TB1.COL1 = TB2.Col1
WHERE
    TB2.COL1 = '12345'
    AND
    (
        TB2.COL3 = COALESCE
        (
            (
                SELECT
                    MIN(TB3.COL4)
                FROM
                    TB3
                WHERE
                    COL1 = TB2.COL1
                    AND COL2 in ('A', 'B')
                    AND COL4 IN
                    (
                        SELECT
                            COL3
                        FROM
                            TB2
                        WHERE
                            COL1 = TB2.COL1
                    )
            ),
            TB2.COL3
        )
    )
    AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and explanation! I didn't think about applying COALESCE. I also agree with using the JOINS in from clause.

Comment: This scenario does not work in every case if TB2.COL3 is NULL. Then the condition evaluates to False. How can we avoid this scenario?

Comment: Another `coalesce()` would do the trick: `COALESCE(TB2.Col3, 1) = COALESCE(<select statement>, TB2.COL3, 1)` this way it will keep going until it hits `1` in both `COALESCES()` and return `TRUE`. Optionally tossing an `OR TB2.COL3 IS NULL` into this bit may do the trick. 50/50 on which one is quicker.